# c++ - function pointer to non-static member function gives error

Tags: c++

I have this class:

```
class MessageSender
{
private:
    std::set<std::string> connectedUsers;
    std::queue<std::string> messages;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> threads;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition_variable;

    static const char* in_filename;
    static const char* out_filename;
    void checkNewMessages();
    void sendAllMessages();
    bool emptyFileIntoQueue(std::string filename);
```

important part:

```
    typedef void (MessageSender::*func_t)();
    typedef std::pair<func_t, const char*> funcPair_t;

    // A vector that holds all functions and their explanations for the menu // null indicates exit option
    const std::vector<funcPair_t> menuFunctions = {
        funcPair_t(&MessageSender::menu_signIn, "Sign in to the messaging list."),
        funcPair_t(&MessageSender::menu_signOut, "Sign out of the messaging list."),
        funcPair_t(&MessageSender::menu_printConnectedUsers, "Show all connected users."),
        funcPair_t(nullptr, "Exit the menu.") };

    // Functions for the menu.
    void menu_signIn();
    void menu_signOut();
    void menu_printConnectedUsers();
```

```
public:
    MessageSender();

    void launchMenu();
    bool signIn(std::string username);
    bool signOut(std::string username);
    void printConnectedUsers() const;
};
```

As you see in the important part I declare a `vector` containing `pair`s of member function pointers and `const char*`s and initialize it at the same line. 
I get this error: " '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression "

The compiler is VS 2013.

Comment: An [mcve] is required to answer this question, and not isolated code fragments. In any case, string literals are `const char *`s, and not `char *`s. That's already an obvious problem. Fix that part of your `std::pair`, first.

Comment: Either the example code differs from the original, or this is a compiler bug. Your use of member function pointers seems correct to me. Works in clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ (although warns of the ill-formed conversions from string literals).

Comment: In your pair you could use `std::string` instead of `char*`, which is obviously wrong. Other than that it works with g++5.1: http://ideone.com/Gve45d